# VBA check if object exists before set

Tags: excel, vba

What is the best way to check if object exists before using set on it ?

I have many workbooks, they contain checkboxes and optionbuttons.
I have an array that contain the list of all possible names of checkboxes and optionbuttons that the different workbooks may have

to make my question clear, let us suppose that i have

```
sArray(i) = "CheckBox15"
```

when I do

`Set s = .OLEObjects(sArray(i))`

is giving me an **error 1004** when there is no a checkbox called "CheckBox15" in the active sheet.

what I want in my below code, is to add a line that tells :

if "CheckBox15" exists on current sheet (ws) then set .... is there any command that check if an object exists ?

```
'ws is the worksheet
Dim s As OLEObject
Dim i As Long

with ws
For i = 0 To UBound(sArray)
Set s = .OLEObjects(sArray(i))
If s.Object.Value = True Then
GetOptionCheck = GetOptionCheck & s.Object.Caption
End If
Next i
end with
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a custom boolean function for a quick check:

```
Public Function objectExists(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByVal someName As String) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo objectExists_Error

    Dim someOle As OLEObject
    Set someOle = ws.OLEObjects(someName)
    objectExists = True

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

objectExists_Error:
    objectExists = False

End Function
```

The call it like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim s As OLEObject
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets(1)
    Dim someArray As Variant
    someArray = Array("CheckBox1", "CheckBox2", "CheckBox3", "CheckBox4")

    With ws
        For i = LBound(someArray) To UBound(someArray)
            If objectExists(ws, someArray(i)) Then
                Set s = .OLEObjects(someArray(i))
                Debug.Print s.object.Caption
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, your solution works fine, I will choose is as selected solution